# Alert is not working with jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$.post("url",
       {
         "reg_image":reg_image,
         "country":country,
         "birth_date":birth_date,
         "u‌​ser_name_refrence":user_name_refrence,
         "about_breif":about_breif
       }, 
       function(data,textStatus){ alert(textStatus); }, 
       "json");
```

it works fine except alert is not working. Why ?

Comment: $.post("url",{"reg_image":reg_image,"country":country,"birth_date":birth_date,"user_name_refrence":user_name_refrence,"about_breif":about_breif},
  function(data,textStatus){
   alert(textStatus);
  }, "json");

Comment: You don't see the alert because the code is posting to the url "url" which doesn't exist, hence the done handler is never called.

Comment: I just wrote url instead of real ur but it really post and save data

Comment: @E.Aziz cud u pls add the code here in the post.

Comment: it seems that it is edited